# How to get value from another class (not Inheritance)

Tags: c#, arraylist

I'm trying to reach something from another class, but it won't work.

```
namespace grafiskdel_1_Adam_Erlandsson {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public List<Arbetare> array;       

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.array = new List<Arbetare>();
    }
}
```

Here is the code from my "Arbetare" class at the moment:

```
namespace grafiskdel_1_Adam_Erlandsson
{
   public class Arbetare : Person
    {

    }
}
```

This is a bit of code my Form1 class, and I'm trying to reach something from the class "Arbetare", but I can't reach it. My programmer teacher told me I can do this, or maybe I am doing something wrong?

I'm trying to reach a variable from the "Arbetare" class to put into my `List<>`. Just ask me if you got any questions :)

Comment: I don't get the error you are facing. Post the code you want to do, and won't compile

Comment: What exactly do you mean that you can't reach it? What's the symptom?

Comment: I assume you are trying to reach a field or member of Arbetare.  However your list is of type Arbetare.  You cannot put anything but an Arbetare in a List<Arbetare> perhaps you can post more code including the member you are trying to access in Arbetare.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to reach an a field or member of Arbetare. That's all the code I have at the moment.

Comment: you're trying to reach something from the class "Arbetare", but that isn't shown - neither is any instance of this class being shown - you can't 'reach' it if it's never created

Comment: You're trying to reach a member of Arbetare, but it doesn't have any members. It's empty. Unless you're trying to reach something that's in Person, but you haven't shown us the code that isn't working. You need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to create a new instance of `Arbetare` and add it to the list.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.array = new List<Arbetare>();
    Arbetare v = new Arbetare();
    this.array.Add(v);

    Arbetrare v1 = this.array[0];

    // this will be true as v and v1 both point to the same instance
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(object.ReferenceEquals(v, v1));  
}

void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    // you can now access any of the items in your array and any of their properties
    // assuming of course some other code hasn't removed them 
    Arbetrare v1 = this.array[0];
}
```

Comment: Understanding the difference between a class and an instance of that class is an important thing to know. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021911/how-do-i-use-classes

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem of scoping, but I'm no C# guru.

Make sure you have the variable you want access to set as public.

Maybe this may help you?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(v=vs.80).aspx